# Facebook graph api create whatsapp template image with resumable upload api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I need help with creating image type whatsapp templates. Based on the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/message-templates/) to create this type of template I need to use the [Resumable Upload API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload/).

However, I have not been successful in numerous attempts. I followed the steps to get the key and post the file. I got the hash that the second step of the Resumable Upload API provides. When I pass as a parameter in the json to create the tempate, the return is always an unsupported file format. I'm loading image/png and image/jpeg MIME files. I'm using the Postman tool.

**Updated steps**

**Step 1: Get upload key**

`https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/727242995025717/uploads`

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/727242995025717/uploads' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer EAAKVbHRiRzUBAG1HujesBvBuA2ZBbrZAhXuc8aJQVoWhW6IdPeRihH9akMZAyDha5olS4hSXQPSuBZBRVgJA93JLmLQhe0Lz9pXUrxIRXLDzdkwqsReK2UyZBr1YXEMcFYgQUBOlowHlFlWqtXWdJPCGAres7eXtnsqd6nOU4Rqg6B2ZB9e0CnsbOqYhLuZAc70SmtbdjNkagZDZD' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{
    "file_length":"28506",
    "file_type":"image/png",
    "file_name":"test.png"
}
```

*Return*:

```
{
   "id": "upload:MTphdHRhY2htZW50OjgyZWRlNDZhLTA0M2EtNGFkNy04NjNiLTQyNjU0OTAwM2Q4Nj8=?sig=ARYAKCBkBmYa7BkcY_s"
}
```

**Step 2: Post file**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/upload:MTphdHRhY2htZW50OjgyZWRlNDZhLTA0M2EtNGFkNy04NjNiLTQyNjU0OTAwM2Q4Nj8=?sig=ARYAKCBkBmYa7BkcY_s?access_token=EAAKVbHRiRzUBAG1HujesBvBuA2ZBbrZAhXuc8aJQVoWhW6IdPeRihH9akMZAyDha5olS4hSXQPSuBZBRVgJA93JLmLQhe0Lz9pXUrxIRXLDzdkwqsReK2UyZBr1YXEMcFYgQUBOlowHlFlWqtXWdJPCGAres7eXtnsqd6nOU4Rqg6B2ZB9e0CnsbOqYhLuZAc70SmtbdjNkagZDZD' \
--header 'file_offset: 0' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--data-binary '@test.png'
```

*Return*:

```
{
"h":"4:::ARabORl_4eDXWscbjQetu1TN8GWM8042aW6S4gWtDd6wfc0ghJOBiFIdo0iqmQLJTkRr2etuf-U_SfKOSFbNwb-jKvpCR0MEC8hxmkRRHCUq8Q:e:1663677758:727242995025717:100043883327420:ARaa_5q1W1tBJ79gzzk"
}
```

**Step 3: Create the template**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/106148522171805/message_templates' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer EAAKVbHRiRzUBAG1HujesBvBuA2ZBbrZAhXuc8aJQVoWhW6IdPeRihH9akMZAyDha5olS4hSXQPSuBZBRVgJA93JLmLQhe0Lz9pXUrxIRXLDzdkwqsReK2UyZBr1YXEMcFYgQUBOlowHlFlWqtXWdJPCGAres7eXtnsqd6nOU4Rqg6B2ZB9e0CnsbOqYhLuZAc70SmtbdjNkagZDZD' \
--data-raw '{
   "name":"template_cliente_importante",
   "components":[
      {
         "type":"HEADER",
         "format":"IMAGE",
         "example":{
            "header_handle":[
                "4:::ARabORl_4eDXWscbjQetu1TN8GWM8042aW6S4gWtDd6wfc0ghJOBiFIdo0iqmQLJTkRr2etuf-U_SfKOSFbNwb-jKvpCR0MEC8hxmkRRHCUq8Q:e:1663677758:727242995025717:100043883327420:ARaa_5q1W1tBJ79gzzk"
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"BODY",
         "text":"Obrigado por seu contato. Em breve iremos retornar sua solicitacao"
      },
      {
         "type":"FOOTER",
         "text":"Até logo!"
      }
   ],
   "language":"pt_BR",
   "category":"TRANSACTIONAL"
}
```

*Return*:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 2388084,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "File Type Not Supported",
        "error_user_msg": "The type of file is not supported.",
        "fbtrace_id": "A7sDQpYSaCpWFs6oJgVdt-C"
    }
}
```

I believe the error is in step 2, I tried several ways of implementation. I can get other types of templates. However media type templates always return an error.

I appreciate everyone's support!

Tks

Comment: you need to pass the same id that is returned in the first step into the second step's URL. it looks different id in your question.. second, make sure you are passing `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` header in second step.

Comment: Hi, @turivishal
Thanks for your comment. You are correct about, in the example above I mistakenly passed the wrong ID in Step2. I already corrected the example.
I made another attempt now. This time with the correct ID and passing the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. Again I got the error: `"error_user_msg": "The type of file is not supported."`.
Tks

Answer (score 3):

problem solved. The error was in Step 1, note that it was passing `Content-Type: text/plain`. When I switched to `Content-Type: application/json`. The post worked correctly.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/727242995025717/uploads?access_token=EAAKVbHRiRzUBAG1HujesBvBuA2ZBbrZAhXuc8aJQVoWhW6IdPeRihH9akMZAyDha5olS4hSXQPSuBZBRVgJA93JLmLQhe0Lz9pXUrxIRXLDzdkwqsReK2UyZBr1YXEMcFYgQUBOlowHlFlWqtXWdJPCGAres7eXtnsqd6nOU4Rqg6B2ZB9e0CnsbOqYhLuZAc70SmtbdjNkagZDZD' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "file_length":"28506",
    "file_type":"image/png",
    "file_name":"test.png"
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Hugs

Comment: Note that you posted your ACCESS_TOKEN in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

please someone help needed.
when i perform step 2 above, i get facebook page says Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on it and we'll get it fixed as soon as we can.
2 weeks already with that step, i have tried all.
thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Have you been solved this issue, because I am facing the same problem?